# Fixing imprecise stylus drag in Windows 8 & 10

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, touchscreen, stylus

Shortly after I started using Windows 8, I noticed click & drag behaves differently when using a mouse vs a stylus.

With a mouse, the drag begins at the location where the cursor was when the button was depressed:

[image: Demo of a drag with mouse - selection box starts at point of click]

With a stylus, it appears that the drag isn't recognized until the cursor has traveled 10 pixels from where it first pressed:

[image: Demo of a drag with stylus - selection box starts after pen has moved 10px right]

(In the examples above I'm using Greenshot to try to screengrab a rectangle whose upper-left corner starts at the crosshairs in the background. I also encounter the issue in the Unity editor)

I'm guessing this was done to support the new touch features - when using an imprecise finger on a touchscreen, a user wouldn't want slightly wiggly clicks being interpreted as swipes.

But when using a more precise input device like a stylus, this can be quite disruptive. In drawing programs, a drawn stroke will fail to replicate the input stroke by a noticeable gap. When trying to drag items from a list view, the 10px error is enough to grab an adjacent item in the list instead of the intended one.

[When I was using a Wacom tablet, the recommended fix was to go into the Wacom tablet settings and disable "Use Windows Ink"](http://forum.wacom.eu/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=14722)

Unfortunately, my current problem is with the pen that came with my Surface Pro 3, so twiddling Wacom settings isn't available here.

Comment: I suspect this has to do with more with the Pen then anything.  But, twiddling the settings is possible, just have to go through the [normal](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/apps-and-windows-store/surface-app?os=windows-10#AdjustW10) windows way.  Windows Ink might or might not be possible to disable, wouldn't want to do that, might want to try the current Inside Preview since Windows Ink is a huge priority.

Comment: The article might be for Surface Pro 3, if that is the case, then it is indeed the hardware not the software.

Comment: @Ramhound I doubt it's intrinsic to the hardware for a couple of reasons: 1) identical symptoms with Wacom tablets had a software solution, 2) Windows's own desktop drag selection works correctly with the stylus. I suspect that Windows is applying some software processing to the stylus input to interpret it for programs that aren't Ink-aware, and unfortunately it's processing it like a finger instead of like a mouse. That, to me, sounds like something I might be able to fix through a registry setting or driver fiddle. Unfortunately the configuration panel you link does not expose this option.

Comment: Must have sent you in the correct direction though :-). Was leaning towards the pen pressure sensitivity differences between SP3 and SP4 and wacom tablets hence my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha! Turning off Pen Flicks seems to correct for this.

[image: Type "pen" in Start menu and select "Pen and Touch" from the results]
[image: Go to the "Flicks" panel and uncheck "Use flicks..."]

(I thought I'd done that when I first started using this machine - it's part of my usual checklist of disruptive Windows defaults to undo - but it looks like I missed it on this device)