# Fixing "touch ring" lag with wacom pen (not drawing tablet) win 10

Tags: windows-10, stylus

So I recently got a 2-in-1 device with a wacom digitizer, for uni. I ran into an issue I have now seen addressed by many people on the web, but none of the recommended fixes have worked for me. 
This issue can be found documented
here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haoajtCUkFY
here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9d3ynnOX3pw
here:
[Fixing imprecise stylus drag in Windows 8 & 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1063546/fixing-imprecise-stylus-drag-in-windows-8-10)
TL;DR There is a slight delay before dragging action by the stylus is recognized. The suggested fix is to turn off flicks and "Press and hold for right click" in the Windows 10 "Pen and Touch" (under the "Pen" section) settings, which I did.
 I ended up having to turn off the Right-Click function in *Touch* settings also, before the functionality disappeared, which makes absolutely no sense on windows' side. This *also* didn't remove the delay. I also have all the latest drivers. Is there **anything** to be done about this ridiculous bug by Microsoft?